# Can't find inverted google play badges

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I happen to be going back to an old project, where I used the old inverted google play badge (mainly white colored) on a dark footer.

But, I happen to come across that the badge is now updated since 2022, and I think that it is now only available in only black from what I can see on google play badges page.

Is there any way to get the updated version but mainly white to have on darker backgrounds?

I can't seem to find it anywhere. And I don't want to use badges from third party sites.

I can't get a hold of an inverted google play badge. I see that apple has one black and one white, but can't seem to find one from Google with the same alternative.

Comment: You could try CSS filter invert(). https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.php

Comment: Thanks but the problem is if i were to make this site official and earn money from it and i were to use a logo that is not directly from google cant i get in licensing trouble?

Comment: As far as I can see Google play logo is a triangle of 4 colors. This should be okay on a dark background. Or maybe you mean something else?

Comment: No you are right. it can be used and its decently visible. It just goes better against the dark background if the backgroundcolor of the badge was white. As in their previous iteration. Thanks anyways. ill have to use the badge provided by google!